# Unable to work with Django (python 2.7, OS X 10.11.1)

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I'm about to pull my hair out in frustration. Trying to start a Django project on my new iMac with OS X El Capital. Python 2.7 came installed on the computer, and it seems so was Django. However, I can't run django-admin. I've got Django installed on my laptop and I didn't have this much trouble.

Per the official documentation, I try

```
pip install --upgrade Django==1.9.8
```

and the terminal returns

`Requirement already up-to-date: Django==1.9.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.8-py2.7.egg`

Then I try in python:

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.9
```

Great! Next I try:

```
Django-admin.py --version
```

and it returns

```
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
```

After googling it, seems that the path may be the issue? I try:

```
echo $PATH
```

and I get

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

On the docs for troubleshooting, "django-admin should be on your system path if you installed Django via python setup.py" so I try that.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

A bunch of stuff happens, and then

`Extracting Django-1.9.8-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Django 1.9.8 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing django-admin.py script to /usr/local/bin
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py'`

So in summary, it seems that Django is installed and I can import and find its version through python. However, I cannot run django-admin.py or django-admin.

Please help!!

Comment: Are you trying to install in a virtual environment or globally?

Comment: Also why are you using Python 2.7 for a brand new project in 2016?

Comment: Well, you can always try to put `django-admin.py` in `/usr/local/bin/` _manually_: copy it from the installation package you downloaded, go to Finder, hit `Cmd+G`, enter the path, hit `go` (or something like this - I don't remember exactly) and paste this file there. By the way, thanks for paying attention to formatting and providing details of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it in a virtualenv.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv # create virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate  # activate venv
pip install --upgrade Django==1.9.8  # install django in your venv
django-admin  # should run django-admin from your venv
```

Running in a venv is always cleaner IMO, it allows you to have different projects using their own venv without conflicting and you can get rid of your venv when you are done with it by simply deleting the folder.

Comment: I was really hoping this would work. Trying to install virtualenv didn't work. I went through a googling Bonanza trying to figure out why installing virtualenv won't work (the instructions all make it seem super easy, and it should be!). The wierdest thing is - when I change directly into the usr/local/bin directory and try to run python django-admin.py, it says no such file or directory exists though I can see it when I ls the directory! I'm so confused!

Comment: Bash doesn't include your current directory as being part of your PATH, therefore you need to specify the absolute path to the file you want to run by prefixing with `./` So in your case, you would move into the folder and call `./python django-admin.py`

Comment: Also, when you say, that you cannot install virtualenv, do you mean you aren't able to install virtualenv per say or you cannot create a virtualenv? If you aren't able to install virtualenv at all then I suggest you reinstall python altogether.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Virtualenv was the solution. It took a while but reinstalling Python fixed the issue.